# Is there any way to compile code ( C/ C++ ) with in browser?

Tags: api, google-chrome, compiler-construction, online-compilation

This question may sound crazy.Is there anything browser based compiler out there 
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) is a sandbox for running compiled C and C++ code in the browser efficiently. You can explore this.

Comment: Can you please explain , where does the compilation part takes place ?. Because it running compiled C and C++ code. Am I right ?

Comment: Native Client web application consists of JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and a NaCl module written in a language supported by the SDK. The NaCl SDK currently supports C and C++. Please go through this [video](https://youtu.be/MvKEomoiKBA)  & this [website](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/overview) for understanding it better.

Comment: Native Client is now obsolete, so it [will be removed from Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/migration) later this year.

Comment: Native client has been removed as of 2022.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to run native binaries in a browser using an [x86 emulator in JavaScript](https://github.com/copy/v86), so a C compiler could run in a browser in this way.

It is also possible to write a "self-hosting" C-to-WebAssembly compiler that runs in a browser, such as [emception](https://github.com/jprendes/emception).

Answer (score 2):

You can run linux in the browser, it also has the gcc compiler which you can use from the command line:
[jslinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/)